# Putting my 32 bits into a 4 bytearray

Tags: java, parsing, arrays

I am putting different binary numbers into a byte array. One of the numbers are: `10001101010010010000000000001000` this number is giving me a `NumberFormatException` on the line where I try to parse it, obviously because it's too big. See code below where `string` is the binary number.

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(string, 2);
ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(number);
byte[] byteInstruction = bytes.array();
```

What I want is to put the numbers in my byte array but as they are 32-bit numbers I don't want to take up more than 4 bytes in my array. When I use long to parse it works but then I take up 8 spaces in my byte array.

```
long number = Long.parseLong(string, 2);
ByteBuffer bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(number);
byte[] byteInstruction = bytes.array();
```

If I print out the array later I get this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, -115, 73, 0, 8]
```

where we can see that there are 4 spots free. How can I solve this? How did I mess up?
All help is appreciated.

Comment: The point is that the number does not fit into an `int` because in Java an `int` is signed.

Comment: You didn't mess anything up. A long is 64 bits, or 8 bytes

Comment: @cricket_007 But what can I do? As I want to store my number in only 4 spaces in my byte array and not 8.

Comment: I don't think that number is too big for an int. It's just a large negative number if it is signed

Comment: use `int number = (int)Long.parseLong(string,2);`

Comment: @MattTimmermans Wouldn't number get a false value due to casting?

Comment: only if the string was longer than 32 digits.  If that's going to be a problem, then you should check for that before parsing it

Comment: @MattTimmermans Won't it fail because 10001101010010010000000000001000 = 2,370,371,592 and an int has max value of 2,147,483,647?

Comment: Nope.  When you cast a long to an int, it keeps the lower 32 bits and throws the upper 32 bits away.  This will result in a negative int if bit 31 (the sign bit) is set.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input string `"10001101010010010000000000001000"` represents value that is too big for **signed** `Integer`. [`Integer.MAX_VALUE = 2147483647`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) and the input string you've passed has a value of `2370371592`.

The `Integer.parseInt` **does not interpret** the leading `1` at position 32 from right as *sign*. If you would like parse a negative value it would have to be preceded with `-` sign.

See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888969/155213) for more through explanation.

If you expect the input `"10001101010010010000000000001000"` to in fact mean `"-0001101010010010000000000001000"` just replace the first character with `+`/`-` depending on the value of 32 bit from right.

Alternatively if you would like to treat the binary string in [Two's complement compatible way](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#cite_note-5) you can use approach from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410168/how-to-parse-negative-long-in-hex-in-java):

```
int msb = Integer.parseInt("1000110101001001", 2);
int lsb = Integer.parseInt("0000000000001000", 2);

int result = msb<<16 | lsb;
```

Comment: For example, it turns 10000000000000000000000000000000 into -0

Comment: Integer.MIN_VALUE.  See the two's compliment link in my comment on the question

Comment: @MattTimmermans see my edit. You could also add the two's complement requirement to the question so that it would be easier to find