# Long.parseLong throws NumberFormatException for valid hex string

Tags: java, string, parsing, hex, long-integer

I am trying to parse a long number from hex string `"c022b5b52124944b"` by simply calling

```java
Long l = Long.parseLong("c022b5b52124944b", 16);
```

but it throws a NumberFormatException:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "c022b5b52124944b"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:444)
```

I don't really get why since

```java
Long l = 0xc022b5b52124944bL;
```

works perfectly fine. What am I missing?

Comment: Ok, I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410168/how-to-parse-negative-long-in-hex-in-java which answers my question.

Comment: `long l = Long.parseUnsignedLong("c022b5b52124944b", 16);`